# find bubble text using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

i have a question what is the best method to find speech bubble text using opencv? this is for my final project to graduate from collage and i also have trouble reading some other language than english

example image :
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiTW4.jpg)

there's some method or algorithm i though could be useful to read the page clearly

```
def find_adaptive_threshold(file,visualize=False):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    adaptive_threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C ,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,81,11)
    if visualize:
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15,10))
        axes[0].imshow(rgb)
        axes[0].set_title('Original image')
        axes[1].imshow(adaptive_threshold, cmap='gray')
        axes[1].set_title('adaptive threshold image')
    return adaptive_threshold
```

result method 1 = [method 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kILzH.jpg)

```
def blur_method(img_file,visualize=False):
    img = cv2.imread(img_file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(7,7),0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,13))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations=1)

    cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cnts = sorted(cnts,key=lambda x:cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])
    
    if visualize:
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15,10))
        axes[0].imshow(img)
        axes[0].set_title('Original image')
        axes[1].imshow(dilate, cmap='gray')
        axes[1].set_title('Preprocessed image')
```

result method 2 = [method 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nLt5.png)

## result using blur method :

[final-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGNVM.png)

how do i to find speech bubbles using opencv and what kind algorithm that recognized the shape of the  speech bubbles... to detect text i using `tesseract OCR`. I don't have any idea how to solve this problem

i want to find the shape of the speech bubble text using opencv and then using OCR to recognize the text after that, translate the text into the other languages

Thank You

Comment: By the way a good challenging question, I liked it

Answer (score 0):

I have a good idea which can solve your problem. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Apply the text detection algorithm: There are different kind of text detection algorithms like **tesseract**, **easyOCR**, etc. You can continue one of these. Since your texts are clear, it would be easy to detect. I suggest you to use easyOCR. At the end of this operation, you will get a rectangle with points which contains the text.
2. use [fillPoly()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga311160e71d37e3b795324d097cb3a7dc) function to fill with white pixels inside this rectangle. By this, all of the bubble will be same color.
3. This is the complicated step. Find all the contours in the text rectangle area. And find the parent contour of that rectangle. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) is a beatiful example about **contour hierarchy**.

I hope this helps, please comment below for unclear parts.

Comment: so at the first step is, i should find the contours of the shape bubble speech, so it can give clearly for ```tesseract``` to recognize. But here the main problem to find shape it's really complicated, many of bubble speech have irregular size. but thank for advice

Comment: actually no, at the first step apply a text detection algorithm to all image and it will give you the regiong of text in a rectangle.